# Did not find how to add 'additivity' for a logger in Jboss AS 7

Tags: logging, jboss

We have migrated from Jboss 4 to Jboss 7. In Jboss 4 we used log4j.xml and have added 'additivity' property to child loggers so that the log messages do not propogate to its parents, but I do not know how to add the same in Jboss 7 logger. Can anyone please help.

The requirement is to not propogate the messages from a child logger to its parent.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `use-parent-handlers` attribute on the logger to `false`.

```
<logger category="org.jboss" use-parent-handlers="false" />
```

(tried it on AS 7.1.2)